# How to translate page titles?

Tags: routes, 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using the awesome [Internationalization Module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) for managing the translations of my multilingual website. The name of each menu item also becomes the page title (the HTML TITLE tags). When switching languages everything works perfectly except the page titles. The page title shows correctly the name of the page, but in the LAST language I translated that menu link into. The last added translation of the menu is Chinese, so the page titles are always Chinese, regardless wheter you are on the Swedish or French version of that page.

- Using Drupal 7.18
- Using Internationalization module 7.x-1.7, fully enabled.
- The multilingual options of the menu are set to 'Translate and Localize. Menu items with language will allow translations. Menu items without language will be localized.'

What could I try to fix this?

Comment: Is the problem with the page title or the menu item?  These are different things, and your question isn't clear.

Comment: The internationalization module allows one to translate the menu. The name of the menu items also become the page titles.

Comment: Menu item names don't become page titles automatically.  How are you converting the menu item names into page titles?

Comment: With page titles I mean the actual HTML TITLE TAG. The title that appears on top of the browser and is of great importance for multilingual SEO. If Drupal does not automatically makes clicked menu items also the page title, then it's probably the Internationalization Module managing this for me. Possibly it's a bug in the module?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details about how you have configured your content to be displayed.  I can tell you that the suite of i18n modules is usually able to translate page titles/menu titles without trouble, so there is probably something odd in your configuration.  If you are trying to translate Views titles, you should try the Internationalization Views module, although it has a fair number of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to update to version 7.x-1.8 of the Internationalization Module. This was a bug in version 7.x-1.7. Thank you developers! Drupal FTW :D

Answer (score 1):

while translaing page, there is an option at bottom 'provide a menu link'. check this field with title...

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain with a screenshot or something ?

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: Thank you Monymirza, that's indeed a good way to go if you have one node per menu item. All my pages consist of several views, containing multiple nodes. Unfortunately I cannot use this method :(

Answer (score 0):

You cant try it out this module [Title](http://drupal.org/project/title/) for drupal 7.Hope this will give you good solution.

Comment: Thank you Ranjani, this module edits the node title, not the page title. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Apex.Sorry I can't get you.Can you explain your needs elaborately?

Comment: I wish to translate the page titles. This is the actual HTML TITLE tag. This title appears on top in the browser and is of great importance for multilingual SEO. The module you suggest unfortunately is to edit node titles.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the page titles with string override methods.

for that you needs to edit in page.tpl

```
      <?php print $title; ?> will be <?php print t($title); ?>
```

Comment: Never use `t()` for variables, it's only meant for string literals.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/localization-api/dynamic-strings-with-placeholders
If you want to translate node titles, use a module designed for that. Likely one which relies on the i18n module package.